# Locating a copy of a thesis

Tags: reference-request, logic, topos-theory

Does anyone have a transmittable copy of the thesis "Logical and cohomological aspects of the space of points of a topos" by Carsten Butz? The link provided in http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/point+of+a+topos seems to be dead, and I can't seem to find a copy elsewhere.

Comment: Also, you could get it from Utrecht itself. http://dspace.library.uu.nl:8080/simple-search?query=Logical+and+cohomological+aspects+of+the+space+of+points+of+a+topos&submit=Go  --- for a price.

Comment: It is available on academia.edu: http://www.academia.edu/9139781/Logical_and_Cohomological_Aspects_of_the_Space_of_Points_of_a_Topos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently he used to have some affiliation with http://www.itu.dk/. You might try contacting them.

You could also try contacting the author of the article you mention: http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Urs+Schreiber.

There is also this: http://books.google.com/books/about/Logical_and_cohomological_aspects_of_the.html?id=fzP8AQAACAAJ.

Hopefully one of these pans out for you.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I'll send an email to Mr. Schreiber; with luck he'll have a copy.